# HTML canvas failing to draw after adding elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempting to draw using canvas, and everything works only for a moment: after I append elements to the div (`#workbench`) which is the parent for my `canvas`, 1. drawing gets removed 2. Any more attempts at drawing using this canvas do not work.

Screenshot: a test image drawn with canvas, green background is the canvas space, pink is the website background
[image]

And this is the JS code:
(called once)

```js
var canvas1 = document.querySelector('#workbench_canvas');
var workplace = document.querySelector('#workbench');

console.log(canvas1);
if (!canvas1 || !canvas1.getContext) {
    console.error("ERROR");
}


canvas1.width       = workplace.offsetWidth;
canvas1.height      = workplace.offsetHeight;
```

(called every time I want to draw shapes)

```js
function draw1(){   
    let ctx = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    console.log("drawing with context", ctx);

    ctx.fillStyle='yellow';
    for (var i=0;i<5;++i) ctx.fillRect(i*18+2,2,16,16);

    ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(100, 140);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 140);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle = '#D0D044';
    ctx.fillRect(120, 140, 160, 550);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#2222AA';
    ctx.fillRect(200, 180, 20, 20);
    return "Successfully drawn";
}
draw1();
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you "_append elements to the div_"? I suspect that div contains the canvas, and you're using `innerHTML` and `+=` operator instead of really appending.

Comment: Yes I'm using `.innerHTML += ...`

Comment: That is not appending. `innerHTML` is a string, and strings in JS are immutable. `+=` is just a shortcut to `.innerHTML = .innerHTML + something`, when set, it removes the current elements and creates new elements. That way the reference to the canvas element stored in `canvas1` variable becomes obsoleted, because the canvas doesn't exist anymore. See [DOM manipulating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) to find a proper way to append elements to your page.